# UIImage View over navBar and statusBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

i wanted to ask you if it is possible to overlay an image to a navigation bar and statusBar just to obscure them as the twitter integration form does... Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use model view controller to accomplish this, you can read this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/03/ipad-modal-view-controllers.html) to learn how to use it.